# Vista & Cookies

Tags: firefox, cookies, windows-vista

Does anybody know where are cookies stored in Windows Vista?
I'm looking at C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies but the cookies I see there don't match the one I see through Firefox.

I'm creating a cookie in ASP.NET, localhost, Firefox shows me the cookie but I cannot locate it in the file system.

Any ideas?
Tks

Comment: I don't see how this is not programming related. A program created the cookies, or was it a shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On vista:
C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\someRandomNumbers.default\cookies.sqlite

Answer (score 2):

I think FireFox stores cookies in its own storage, not under the Cookies folder in the profile. This is where IE stores its cookies.

On my system (XP Pro with FireFox 3.0.10), cookies seem to be stored unter C:\Documents And Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Mozilla\FireFox\Profiles... in a SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Privacy -> Show Cookies.

Comment: I know that one, it's stated in my question. But thanks anyway.

Comment: then it's an odd question. what do you expect to get out of the sqlite file that you can't get through the options interface?

Comment: The question was where is physically Firefox getting the cookie data from? I didn't know it was from SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Non persistent cookies are kept in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not a shared space for cookies, they are browser depedent. Strange, if a web site is sending a cookie to the client, why shouldn't all browsers share the same cookie?

If someone implements a single sing on mechanism for site authentication.... it will be limited to a single browser, you still need to authenticate for each browser you may use.